# Error: Cannot find module './'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, electron

I stumbled upon this error when trying to start my application via NPM start. I am not sure where the problem lies, because it worked fine in my other computer (I unzip the file to this computer ran, npm install just in case and then tried to start it, but then the following error is thrown below).

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    module.js:340
        throw err;
              ^
    Error: Cannot find module './'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/client/<NAME>/node_modules/.bin/electron:3:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

    npm ERR! Linux 3.4.0+
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
    npm ERR! node v0.10.46
    npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! <NAME>@0.0.0 start: `electron main.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 8
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the <NAME>@0.0.0 start script 'electron main.js'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the <NAME> package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     electron main.js
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs <NAME>
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls <NAME>
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "<NAME>",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "[..]",
  "main": "index.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "test.321",
    "app-category-type": "your.app.category.type",
    "win": {
      "iconUrl": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js",
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "author": "john@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.3.3",
    "electron-installer-squirrel-windows": "^1.3.0",
    "electron-packager": "^7.5.1"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

***After solving the above error, the following error is thrown***

I am running this through bash on windows 10, and have tried to install all required libraries to get the electron app to start via npm start on windows (works fine in my ubuntu)

> electron main.js

```
    [8002:0814/084446:FATAL:render_sandbox_host_linux.cc(40)] Check failed: 0 == shutdown(renderer_socket_, SHUT_RD). shutdown: Invalid argument
    #0 0x000001e098ce <unknown>
    #1 0x000001e1f4db <unknown>
    #2 0x000001e1fa9d <unknown>
    #3 0x000002892fc2 <unknown>
    #4 0x00000265e599 <unknown>
    #5 0x000002664b5f <unknown>
    #6 0x00000265dc36 <unknown>
    #7 0x000001204157 <unknown>
    #8 0x000001202c30 <unknown>
    #9 0x0000033a9470 main
    #10 0x7fe5ec701f45 __libc_start_main
    #11 0x000000575039 <unknown>
```

Comment: Could you share your package.json or a file where all the list of packages stored!

Comment: sure just shared my package.json file. Have a look!

Comment: Just a theory: Try removing `node_modules` completely and running `npm install` again. `.bin` has symlinks to original package fails and it may be lost during zip/unzip and not be overwritten/fixed with `npm installing` maybe.

Comment: Try set NODE_PATH to current folder e.g. `NODE_PATH=.`

Comment: Make sure you ran `npm install` with sufficient administrator rights. On OSX run it with `sudo`, for example.

Comment: @John looks like there are issues with your index.html page where u are loading your packages.

Comment: thank you guys setting the NODE_PATH solve the issue.

Comment: When i tried to do NPM start, I unexpectly ran into a weird error. I have added an update section on my initial post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shutdown` check fail is a [known issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6722). Electron runs just fine as a native Windows app, so just do that instead of over-complicating things with Bash on Windows.

Comment: where i can find electron navitve windows app for development, and isn;t better to work with the official one which is unix based

Comment: @John Electron is multi-platform, it officialy supports macOS, Windows, and Ubuntu. You install Electron on Windows using `npm install electron`, same way you do on the other platforms, just do it in a regular Windows terminal window rather than Bash on Windows. Just make sure your Windows environment is properly configured for building native Node modules, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools and https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#configuring-your-windows-development-environment

Comment: ok thank you. Out of curiosity, when is it proper to use bash then?

Comment: @John Bash on Windows is meant to be used for running Linux utilities / shell scripts that aren't available on Windows, as stated in the overview here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about